# Java::Initialize multiple static objects easily

Tags: java, initialization

I have multiple objects of `class A`.
Since these objects are textures being used in game, they have distinctive names that indicate their use.
ex) bttnDoor bttnPause bttnExit bttn....
So I do not want to make them as array (even though if I had an array, I could use loop to initialize them).

I tried

`a = b = c = new Object();` but since they are mutable, they all point to the same object.

it appears the only way to initialize them distinctively is

```
a = new Ob...


b = new Ob...


c = new Ob...
```

however the choir of hard coding extends itself exponentially as the development progresses (more textures).

is there an easier way to initialize multiple objects with distinctive objects?

Comment: I would hope the number of textures doesn't increase *exponentially* - quite the reverse. As the game increases, I'd expect the number of new textures you add per extra part to *decrease*, as you reuse existing ones.

Comment: since it's 2d game we r having different texture for different monsters, blocks and so on, but I guess if we somehow manage to reuse them, and it sounds like we should do so, i am not supposed to have this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using reflections. It is rather not recommended, but it solves your problem.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Example {

    Integer f1;
    String f2;
    Example f3;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
         Example obj = new Example();
         for (Field f : Example.class.getFields()) {
            f.set(obj,  f.getType().newInstance());
         }
   }
 }
```

Edit:
I've enhanced it with possibility of having different types

Comment: but I have multiple type of objects more than just Object. So not all objects should be initialized as an Object. So I guess this approach does not fit me either OTL.

Comment: I've enhanced my example with possibility of having different types. Unfortunately your classes must have default constructors.

Comment: seems really there isn't an appropriate way to do this... maybe I am not supposed run into this problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

No.without `new` key word you **cannot** create a `instance` of the `class`.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `enum` type. Enums have syntax useful for this particular purpose.

You can have all the textures implement an inherited type. Then, do something like:

```
public enum Textures {
    TEXA (new TextureA()),
    TEXB (new TextureB());
    //...

    private Texture s;
    public Texture getTexture() {return s;}

    Textures(Texture s) {this.s = s;}
}
```

While this does not directly solve your problem, there is no way to directly solve your problem. Another solution could be to use an array of textures, but that would be rather messy.

Read more about the enum type [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: but still.. shouldn't i have to write TexA(new TextureA() ),B(new TextureA() ),C(new TextureA() ),D(new TextureA() )... and so on? I don't see any difference from doing a = new Texture();

Comment: Yes, you will have to do that. If you want to reference internal textures by an object name, then you will have to specify the object name and the object itself _somewhere_. Enums just make it friendlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an IOC container to get this done more easily.

Or you can use a factory method like the below one to initialize the variables.

```
public static void initializeObjects(Object... params){
   for(Object obj:params){
    obj=new Object();
   }
}
```

Calling it is easy as

```
Object a;
Object b;
Object c;

initializeObjects(a,b,c);
```

EDIT :

Actually this will not work. I must apologize for such a simple oversight. The reason is that the newly created instances will not reflect in the original variables.

This is due to the fact that Java passes object references by value. So the original declaration will still point to `null`.

@Telthien Thanks for starting me on this chain of thoughts.

However let me point out that in OPs question he had the following snippets

```
a = b = c = new Object();
```

Which led me to believe that the object creation didn't involve any changing initialization parameters resulting in my flawed answer..

Comment: ???? I am very confused. Shouldn't the obj be gone once it's out of scope? I tried Objects[] arr = new Objects[]{a,b,c} then looping through them while assigning new object to each, that didn't work?

Comment: yes it goes out of scope... maybe this approach works if object a was created/defined in the same scope but i have global variable a that exists outside of the scope.

Comment: This assumes the objects are all of the same type, which they explicitly are not.

Comment: this is wrong, as the a copy of the pointer of the object is sent to the method. so changing the object it self will not change the original object.

Comment: Yes I realized that and edited the question just before your comment :-)